# htaccess 301 redirect - subfolder selection only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all the subfolders that come under /timetables and only the subfolders because the new website also has the main folder /timetables.

What i need is when a user types in /timetables/timetable1 they are redirected to /timetables

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/timetables /timetables
```

<-- This sort of redirect has worked for me well when the new path is different to the old but when it is the same i get a redirect loop on the page.

Is there any way of selecting just the subfolders of a directory and redirecting them?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i need is when a user types in /timetables/timetable1 they are redirected to /timetables

You can use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(timetables)/.+ /$1/
```